# Using Microsoft Data Access Components 2.8 in 64bit IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6, 64-bit

we have been running a set of sites in IIS 6, windows server 2003 R2, in 32Bit compatability mode for sometime. I have recently been pondering if we can switch this mode off and run native 64bit, letting IIS handle 32bit COM Components etc.

However upon looking into it and testing some ideas I have found that our ASP sites fall over with the following error:

METADATA tag contains a Type Library specification that does not match any Registry entry.

The global.asa is including

I believed that the 64Bit versions of MDAC was included within MS Server 2003, does anyone have any advice / solutions?

I'm beginning to think I may be bound to the 32Bit compatibility mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more hunting I found the issue.

The code was using NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library" UUID="{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" VERSION="2.6" which is only 32bit

To use the 64 bit version you have to upgrade to 2.8

NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" UUID="2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C"

note it has a different UUID